# WebStorm: How to save terminal sessions after restart?

Tags: webstorm

Using WebStorm 9 on Windows how I can save terminal sessions after IDE restart?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ATM - no way.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117946 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.